# How i can restrict specific users to access few web methods in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

if my web service has 5 methods, say method1(), method2(), method3(),method4() and method5().
and two clients a and b. then is it possible that client a only see method1() and method2(). and client b only see method 3,4 and 5.

is it possible in webservice? if yes , then how?

Comment: I dont know what you are trying achieve .. From the implementation point it is simpler to provide two APIs - one exposes method1() method2 and the other methods 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: if i create two different APIs then they will have two different URL. which is not my requirement. can i handle this? that is , to have different APIs and both can be referenced by one URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mean 'call' by 'see': yes. You could test the credentials of the user and accordingly grant or deny access.

When you mean 'published in meta data (MEX/WSDL)' by 'see': yes, but not easily.

You could publish customized meta data for each user(group) and grant/deny access to the meta data. Visual Studio does not support this scenario; you'll have to adjust the WSDL and control access.

Another thing is that Visual Studio does not allow you to pass credentials to the site when trying to retrieve meta data other than by running Visual Studio as that user. So this might hinder you in setting a service reference.

You could turn of security for a while to circumvent this.